# jquery autocomplete not clearing choices?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I was just playing around with jquery autocomplete. I've set the minimum length to 3.

if I typed in the letters "sci" it would then get all records that has the letters "sci" in the title. This part is **working** correctly as all records with the letters "sci" are returned and displayed.

But if say I continue typing (after a pause of course. at this point I typed "scisdfgdsfsd"), it still displays the previous choices. There are certainly no records with titles using the letters "scisdfgdsfsd" in it.

Any ideas on how to fix this? thanks! :)

---

**screenshots of the "error" in action**

working: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a2wuo2aa

not working: http://awesomescreenshot.com/023wuo507

**my jquery code**

```
$(function() {
    $("#course").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $("#commentsSection").hide();
            $("#instanceIdSection").hide();
            $.getJSON("/issu/GetCourses.html", {term: request.term}, function(data, status) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    response(data);
                } else { 
                    getEventComments();
                    getEventSessions();
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert("select");
            getEventComments();
            getEventSessions();
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            alert("change");
            getEventComments();
            getEventSessions();
        }
    });

    function getEventSessions(){
        $.getJSON("/issu/GetEventSessions.html",{description: $("#course").val()}, function(data, status){
            if (data.length != 0) {

                $("#instanceId").empty();
                $.each(data, function () {
                    $("#instanceId").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", $(this)[0]).text($(this)[1]));
                });
                $("#instanceIdSection").show();
            }
        });
    }

    function getEventComments() {
        $.get("/issu/GetEventComments.html",{description: $("#course").val()}, function(data, status){
            if (data.length != 0) {
                $("#comments").text(data);
                $("#commentsSection").show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function you are supplying to the "source" option calls `response()` only when there are options returned. You should also call `response()` when there are no options returned. That will cause the autocompleter to clear the results.

Try:

```
$.getJSON("/issu/GetCourses.html", {term: request.term}, function(data, status) {
    response(data);
    if (data.length == 0) {
        getEventComments();
        getEventSessions();
    }
});
```

Comment: was making some changes last week and completely missed that. thank you! :)